# Problems Getting Subversion + Apache to Work

Tags: svn, apache, mod-dav-svn

Following the instructions in [this helpful guide](http://library.linode.com/linux-tools/version-control/svn), I've been attempting to set up Subversion on my site, using Apache instead of svnserve. Once everything is set up, I'll have a repository at **/srv/svn/myrepository** that is accessible from **code.mydomain.com**.

However, after following all of the instructions in the guide linked above, visiting **code.mydomain.com** displays the contents of the Apache default site, **/var/www** (i.e., "It works!"). This also generates the following error in my Apache log:

```
[Sat Nov 06 10:11:33 2010] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 06 10:11:34 2010] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sat Nov 06 10:11:34 2010] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Sat Nov 06 10:11:34 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_jk/1.2.26 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Here's an edited version of my site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost my.server.ip:80>
        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        ServerName code.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

        <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /srv/svn/myrepository

                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Subversion Repository"
                AuthUserFile /srv/auth/svn/myrepository.htpasswd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance that you're able to provide!

---

Here are the results of some troubleshooting that I've done per the suggestions of other users (thanks very much). In each case, I restarted Apache after making the change, then checked the site to verify the results:

0) I am not connecting via SSL.

1) SVNParentPath is only necessary when multiple repositories are in use-- here, I'm only using one. Nevertheless, I re-did my configuration using SVNParentPath as a test, and got the same result.

2) I attempted to put the Auth options inside a Limit stanza, and got the same result. I then removed all of the Auth options, but got the same result.

3) Having removed all Auth options from the configuration file and received the same result, I don't think this is related to an authorization module; nevertheless, I can confirm that although I do have the dav_svn module loaded, I don't have the authz_svn module loaded.

4) I had already created the repository in the location **/srv/svn/myrepository** . I ran **svnadmin verify** on that location, and the tool reported that all is well.

5) I'm on Debian 5, where Apache runs as www-data; and prior to this I had given www-data:www-data ownership of **/srv/svn** as well as **/srv/svn/myrepository** . I ran **stat** on those directories to verify this.

6) Pinging **code.mydomain.com** shows that it is indeed resolving to the correct IP

7) I ran **a2ensite code.mydomain.com**, which apparently had not been done (oops), and restarted Apache. The folder **/srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs** now contains access.log and error.log, but both files remain empty. Meanwhile, attempting to access **code.mydomain.com** produces the same result as before, and the default Apache error.log contains the same error messages as before.

8) None of the Apache configuration files contain a **NameVirtualHost *:80** line.

Comment: Can you post the contents of default apache log ? can you let us know if it gets updated when you access the "code.mydomain.com" ? Also can you tell us if you have other virutal hosts in the same config ? My wild guess is the request you are making from the browser is answered by the default domiain or some other virtual host?(check if that is true)

Comment: Oh, it's definitely being answered by the default virtual host-- I confirmed this by disabling "default", which caused **code.mydomain.com** to display a completely different site that i hosted elsewhere on the server. Re-enabling "default" brings back the "It works!" page. I just don't know why it's being answered by default at the moment...

Comment: you should have a line NameVirtualHost *:80 somewhere, preferably in apache.conf/httpd.conf.  do that and restart apache.

Comment: also for the heck of it try changing location from / to /svn and see if http://code.mydomain.com/svn works

Comment: do remember that you have restart apache for changes to take effect

Comment: updated my answer check the last two paras.

Comment: What is the configuration file you have your site configuration in ? To my knowledge debian distributions have all the site configurations inside sites-enabled, do you use the same ?

Comment: My configuration file is in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/code.mydomain.com**. Anytime I edit the file, I run **apache2 reload**, which then updates the configuration in **sites-enabled*8 accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all check that you are going to **http** and not **https**.

I am using centos 5.5.  comparing my /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf with what you provide, leads to the following observations.

check:

1. SVNPath should be SVNParentPath
2. try commenting out the AuthType, AuthName, AuthUserFile and Require to see if that works.  Try enclosing them in:

   ```
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
   ...
   </LimitExcept>
   ```
3. these lines are somewhere

   ```
   LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
   LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
   ```
4. that you have done

   ```
   svnadmin create /srv/svn/myrepository
   ```
5. that you have done

   ```
   chown -R apache.apache /srv/svn/myrepository
   ```

   (if you are on debian/ubuntu apache.apache would be www-data:www-data).

it seems you should not put these things in the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/code.domain.com, instead you should be editing /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf (it should already be there and contain more or less the same things that you are trying to put in the site conf file.  remove all the duplicate things from the site conf file).

you will need to put a path in the location, /svn.

Comment: Thanks very much, sir. I've updated the initial post to note the results of implementing these suggestions-- in short, my problem persists, but your excellent suggestions did help me rule out a cause or two.

Comment: i think 4 more lines above the caught sigterm might be useful

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the entirety of what gets written to the error log when I visit code.mydomain.com.

Comment: are you are showing the contents of /srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs/error.log and /srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs/access.log, or of the default apache log?

Comment: Shown here are the contents of the default Apache log. The **/srv/www/code.mydomain.com/logs** directory is empty.

Comment: that probably means that either you havent fixed the permissions for that folder or that the requests are not getting through.  maybe your virtualhost modules are not enabled, or configured properly, check if you have a NameVirtualHost *:80 line anywhere

Comment: also, ping the code.mydomain.com from your workstation to check if it is resolving to the correct IP.

Comment: Thanks as always for your help, sir. I tried your suggestions and have updated the initial post with the results. The problem persists, but again these were excellent suggestions-- I had forgotten to actually enable the site in Apache. Regrettably, the problem persists after having done so.

Comment: The most recent suggestion-- to add the aforementioned settings to mods-available/dav_svn.conf -- did the trick. For whatever reason, it seems that dav_svn will not work on a virtual-host Debian 5 environment... at least, not for me. Many thanks, sir!

Comment: now why exactly that is and how that can be done is a possible good question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make sure the svn sites virtual domain stays on the top of the hierarchy. By default debian systems have the default port configured to the default domain. you might want to change it specific to the domain.

check this link http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread268331.html for some detailed instructions.

The last line "sudo a2ensite svn.example.com" would be important.